# JSON data to be populated in textareas with the use of PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

It would great if somebody can help me.The problem I have is that I'm unable to create JSON objects with the use of PHP where data is taken from MySQL table.'Role' table has a primary key 'role_id'.This field is an option in the dropdown box.Once the user selects one of the values,presses 'Select Role' button, data related to this value such as background,qualifications needs to be populated in textareas below.At the moment,once the button is pressed, word 'undefined' is displayed in each textarea instead of required data.

What is the problem I'm having? Many thanks for your help.

EDIT - data in now populated in textareas but with undefined errors in 'knowledge_and_skills' and 'prof_dev_activities'.Also,it is now only populated for the first record in the 'role' table - so when selecting values in the dropdown box and changing values for 'role_id' - nothing happens.

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/json");

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="bcs_test"; // Database name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM role");
$obj = mysql_fetch_object($result);

$json = json_encode($obj);

echo ($json);
?>

CREATE TABLE role (
  role_id INTEGER(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  background VARCHAR(5000) NULL,
  tasks VARCHAR(5000) NULL,
  knowledge VARCHAR(5000) NULL,
  training VARCHAR(5000) NULL,
  professional VARCHAR(5000) NULL,
  qualifications VARCHAR(5000) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(role_id)
)
```

Comment: Two things - 1. You don't have to put your variables inside strings like that, they're already strings. 2. You're fetching every row with your query, which isn't necessary. But either way, we need to see your javascript code, because that's where the "undefined" is coming from.

Comment: @Tesserex - I've added role_selection.js file for your consideration and all but two textareas are populated.However,only one record is inserted - so changing the dropdown value doesn't have any impact on values inserted into textareas - I'm looking for a fix in 'role selection.js' but can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Creating stubs for console if it don't exist.
// Can be used for logging to the Chrome JavaScript console.
if (!window.console) {
    console = {};
}

console.log = console.log || function() {};
console.warn = console.warn || function() {};
console.error = console.error || function() {};
console.info = console.info || function() {};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


var function1 = new Array();

function1['Systems Development and Maintenance'] = new Array('Applications Support','Business Analysis','Data Analysis','Database Design', 'Documentation/Technical Authoring','Porting/Software Integration','Programming/Software Creation','Safety Engineering','Software Engineering','Systems Design','Systems Integration','Software Testing','Web Site Specialism');
function1['Service Delivery'] = new Array('Computer Operations','Database Administration','Hardware/Software Installation','Help Desk','Installation and Implementation','Network Administration and Support','Network Operations','Service Level Monitoring','User Support'); 
function1['Technical Advice and Consultancy'] = new Array('System Ergonomics Evaluation');
function1['Quality'] = new Array('Quality Standards');
function1['Customer Relations'] = new Array('Marketing','Sales Support'); 
function1['Education and Training'] = new Array('Education and Training Delivery');
function1['Support and Administration'] = new Array('Change Management','Configuration Management','Project Office','Security Administration');



var rolelevel = new Array();

rolelevel['Systems Development and Maintenance'] = new Array();
rolelevel['Systems Development and Maintenance']['Applications Support'] = new Array('ASUP1','ASUP2');
rolelevel['Systems Development and Maintenance']['Business Analysis'] = new Array('ANAL2');
rolelevel['Systems Development and Maintenance']['Data Analysis'] = new Array('DTAN1','DTAN2');
rolelevel['Systems Development and Maintenance']['Database Design'] = new Array('DBDS1','DBDS2');
rolelevel['Systems Development and Maintenance']['Documentation/Technical Authoring'] = new Array('DOCM1','DOCM2');
rolelevel['Systems Development and Maintenance']['Porting/Software Integration'] = new Array('PORT2'); 
rolelevel['Systems Development and Maintenance']['Programming/Software Creation'] = new Array('PROG1','PROG2');
rolelevel['Systems Development and Maintenance']['Safety Engineering'] = new Array('SFEN2');
rolelevel['Systems Development and Maintenance']['Software Engineering'] = new Array('SENG1','SENG2');
rolelevel['Systems Development and Maintenance']['Systems Design'] = new Array('DESN2');
rolelevel['Systems Development and Maintenance']['Systems Integration'] = new Array('SIST1','SIST2');
rolelevel['Systems Development and Maintenance']['Software Testing'] = new Array('TEST1','TEST2');
rolelevel['Systems Development and Maintenance']['Web Site Specialism'] = new Array('WBSP1','WBSP2');

rolelevel['Service Delivery'] = new Array();
rolelevel['Service Delivery']['Computer Operations'] = new Array('COPS0','COPS1');
rolelevel['Service Delivery']['Database Administration'] = new Array('DBDS1','DBDS2');
rolelevel['Service Delivery']['Hardware/Software Installation'] = new Array('HSIN1','HSIN2');
rolelevel['Service Delivery']['Help Desk'] = new Array('HELP0','HELP1','HELP2');
rolelevel['Service Delivery']['Installation and Implementation'] = new Array('INIM1','INIM2');
rolelevel['Service Delivery']['Network Administration and Support'] = new Array('NTAS2');
rolelevel['Service Delivery']['Network Operations'] = new Array('NTOP0','NTOP1','NTOP2');
rolelevel['Service Delivery']['Service Level Monitoring'] = new Array('SLMO2');
rolelevel['Service Delivery']['User Support'] = new Array('USUP1','USUP2');









rolelevel['Technical Advice and Consultancy'] = new Array();
rolelevel['Technical Advice and Consultancy']['System Ergonomics Evaluation'] = new Array('HCEV2');

rolelevel['Quality'] = new Array();
rolelevel['Quality']['Quality Standards'] = new Array('QUST1','QUST2');

rolelevel['Customer Relations'] = new Array();
rolelevel['Customer Relations']['Marketing'] = new Array('MKTG2');
rolelevel['Customer Relations']['Sales Support'] = new Array('SSUP1','SSUP2');

rolelevel['Education and Training'] = new Array();
rolelevel['Education and Training']['Education and Training Delivery'] = new Array('ETDL2');

rolelevel['Support and Administration'] = new Array();
rolelevel['Support and Administration']['Change Management'] = new Array('CHMG2');
rolelevel['Support and Administration']['Configuration Management'] = new Array('CFMG2');
rolelevel['Support and Administration']['Project Office'] = new Array('PROF2');
rolelevel['Support and Administration']['Security Administration'] = new Array('SCAD2');




function setFunction() {
  functiongSel = document.getElementById('function_grouping');
  rolelevelList = function1[functiongSel.value];
  changeSelect('role_level', rolelevelList, rolelevelList);
  setRoleLevel();
}

function setRoleLevel() {
  functiongSel = document.getElementById('function_grouping');
  functionSel = document.getElementById('role_level');
  functionList = rolelevel[functiongSel.value][functionSel.value];
  changeSelect('function2', functionList, functionList);
}

function changeSelect(fieldID, newOptions, newValues) {
  selectField = document.getElementById(fieldID);
  selectField.options.length = 0;
  for (i=0; i<newOptions.length; i++) {
    selectField.options[selectField.length] = new Option(newOptions[i], newValues[i]);
  }
}


function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  setFunction();
});




function select_role ()
{
    var roleLevel = get_role_level();
    console.info("Role level is " + roleLevel + ".");

    var role = request_role_object(roleLevel);
}

function reset_role_fields(role)
{
    console.log("Filling textboxes for the role level " + role.level + ".");
    set_background(role.background);
    set_tasks(role.tasks);
    set_knowledge_and_skills(role.knowledge_and_skills);
    set_training(role.training);
    set_prof_dev_activities(role.prof_dev_activities);
    set_qualifications(role.qualifications);
}

// A fake-function for testing
function request_role_object (level)
{
    console.warn("Faking role object");

    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(
        {
            level: level,
            background: "The dark background.",
            tasks: "No tasks for now.",
            knowledge_and_skills: "Great knowledge and skills!",
            training: "Some training.",
            prof_dev_activities: "Nagging.",
            qualifications: "Google for qualifications."
        }));
}

var obj;

function process_change() {
    // 4 means the response has been returned and ready to be processed
    if (obj.readyState == 4) {
        // 200 means "OK"
        if (obj.status == 200) {
            // process whatever has been sent back here:

            var role_json = this.responseText;
            console.log("Role object in JSON format: " + role_json);
            reset_role_fields(JSON.parse(role_json));

        } else {
            alert("There was a problem in the returned data:\n");
        }
    }
}

function request_url(url) {
  // native  object

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // obtain new object
    obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // set the callback function
    obj.onreadystatechange = process_change;
    // we will do a GET with the url; "true" for asynch
    obj.open("GET", url, true);
    // null for GET with native object
    obj.send(null);
  // IE/Windows ActiveX object
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    if (obj) {
      obj.onreadystatechange = processChange;
      obj.open("GET", url, true);
      // don't send null for ActiveX
      obj.send();
    }
  } else {
    alert("Your browser does not support AJAX");
  }
}

function request_role_object (level)
{
    console.log("Requesting role with level " + level + ".");

    //
    // Change `some-role.json' to the role.php,
    // that will select a row from the table with the `level' specified
    // and return that data in JSON format (google about JSON and see
    // `some-role.json' for example.
    // 

     //var role_cgi = "some-role.json";
        var role_cgi = "role_select.php";
   request_url(role_cgi + "?" + "level=" + level);
}





function get_role_level ()
{
    var role = document.roleForm.function2.value;

    if (0 == role.length)
    {
        console.warn("Role is unknown.");
    }

    return role;
}

function set_background (newValue)
{
    var field = document.roleForm.backgroundtext;
    field.value = newValue;
}

function set_tasks (newValue)
{
    var field = document.roleForm.taskstext;
    field.value = newValue;
}

function set_knowledge_and_skills (newValue)
{
    var field = document.roleForm.knowledgetext;
    field.value = newValue;
}

function set_qualifications (newValue)
{
    var field = document.roleForm.qualtext;
    field.value = newValue;
}

function set_prof_dev_activities (newValue)
{
    var field = document.roleForm.professionaltext;
    field.value = newValue;
}

function set_training (newValue)
{
    var field = document.roleForm.trainingtext;
    field.value = newValue;
}
```